# Simple golfing interpreter

Tags: code-golf, math, interpreter

## Challenge:

Your job is to create a simple interpreter for a simple golfing language.

---

## Input:

Input will be in the form of string separated by spaces.

**You can replace space separation with what you want**

---

## Output:

Output the result (a number or a string) obtained after performing all operations. If there are more than one output join the together to give a single result (no separators). The variable's initial value is always zero. i.e: It start at `0`

---

## Language Syntax :

The language has following operators :

```
inc  ---> add one to variable
dec  ---> remove one from variable
mult ---> multiply variable by 2
half ---> divide the variable by 2
Pri  ---> print the variable to console (or whatever your language has)
exit ---> end the program (anything after this is ignored)
```

---

## Examples:

```
inc inc inc dec Pri exit                 ---> 2
dec inc mult inc inc Pri                 ---> 2
inc inc inc mult half Pri exit inc       ---> 3
inc Pri inc Pri inc Pri exit half mult   ---> 123
Pri exit                                 ---> 0
inc half Pri exit                        ---> 0.5
```

---

## Restriction:

This is code-golf so shortest code in bytes for each language will win.

---

## Note:

- Input will always be valid . (string of operators separated with space)
- You can round down to nearest integer if you don't want decimal places.

Comment: Can I take a list of strings? Can I use another capitalization?

Comment: Add exit case? exit should matter

Comment: @MuhammadSalman how many decimal places should we support? Is it okay if we round down when dividing?

Comment: @Cowsquack : I guess 2 decimal places will be fine ,  although yeah you can round *down* if you want.

Comment: So does that mean it is okay that `inc half Pri` gives 0 instead of 0.5?

Comment: @l4m2 : What do you mean ?

Comment: @Cowsquack : No , this should return 0.5 or 1 , No zero if even a single operation is performed. (I am willing to change it if it makes golfing easier since these things barely matter)

Comment: @MuhammadSalman let's continue this conversation in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte)

Comment: Is it possible to separate each printed value with newlines or should they all be on the same line ?

Comment: @Kaldo : You can separate using new lines

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't call that language "golfing language".

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann : Haha , Well I agree , but golfing language it is

Comment: This is [Deadfish](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish) with double and half instead of square and longer command names

Comment: Should `Pri` print out without newline?

Comment: @idrougge : Yes

Answer (score 9):

## shell + sed + dc, 56 <s>61</s> bytes

```bash
sed '1i0
s/.//2g;y"idmhe"+-*/q";i1
/[*/]/i1+
/P/crdn'|dc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tce9DkAwFAbQ/T6FdGlC@NTqJexioC29iZ9QEhLvXgmL6eR0rXfBardEkmdN1cb017Vj/8aevH@bjnGXd/DWRFJxTh4ZUAzlJdhMzookjbGKkhWhjtGAVUKooDczy9voEB4)

Converts the program into a dc program, then evaluates it as dc code. This takes the input separated by newlines. Note that dc is stack-based and uses reverse polish notation, so `5 2-` gives `3`, and numbers are always rounded down.

The input is first piped to sed

`1i0` on the first line of input, insert (prepend) a 0, this will be the accumulator

`s/.//2g` remove everything but the first character on each line

`y"idmhe"+-*/q"` transliterate `idmhe` into `+-*/q` respectively, + - * / are the arithmetic commands and q quits the program

`i1` on every line insert a `1` - this satisfies addition and subtraction

`/[*/]/` on every line containing * or /, `i1+` additionally insert `1+` because of the preceding `1`, which dc will eventually evaluate into `2`

`/P/` on every line containing P, `crdn` change it into `rdn`, equivalent to reverse the top two elements, to rid the inserted `1`, and duplicate and output as a number without newline (whilst popping it, hence the earlier duplicate) in dc

Now this is evaluated as a dc expression.

Comment: I suppose it's not unreasonable to expect `sed` syntax to become even more alien than previously thought possible when golfing comes into play.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
ḲḢ€O%11ị⁾’‘j“IȮḤH”¤VI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk0Pdyx61LTGX9XQ8OHu7keN@x41zHzUMCPrUcMczxPrHu5Y4vGoYe6hJWGe////z8xLVgDhgKJMhZTUZDAGsWFiIDq3NKcEQgBFAA)

---

Note that the ASCII values of the first characters (`idmhPe`) modulo 11 are unique modulo 6.

---

Using modulo 16:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
ḲḢ€O%⁴ị“ḢwġḞkz’ṃØJ¤VI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk0Pdyx61LTGX/VR45aHu7sfNcwBCpQfWfhwx7zsqkcNMx/ubD48w@vQkjDP////Z@YlK4BwQFGmQkpqMhiD2DAxEJ1bmlMCIYAiAA)

The string that is used to index into is `ḤH‘’IȮ` in this case. The `‘’` are no longer on the boundaries.

Comment: Using 11 bytes to represent a 6-byte string is... too bad. But... `“”` takes 2 bytes, `¤` takes 1 byte, the data itself takes 6 bytes, there are 2 bytes left to do something. Currently it's `⁾` and `j`, but `ịØJ` or `ṃØJ` is much worse, and `Ọ` doesn't work (because Unicode).

Comment: jli's string concept ("A string is a list of integers with a special flag to affect printing") is great.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>128</s> 125 bytes

```r
Reduce(function(x,y)switch(y,i=x+1,d=x-1,m=x*2,h=x/2,P={cat(x);x}),substr(el(strsplit(gsub("e.*$","",scan(,""))," ")),1,1),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYhLDsIgFACvQoiLR31@6NZwh8YbUErlJZQaPpHGeHasWzczk4nN0xh13GCx2a1TEu1up2IszCWYTGuAiptIL8rGwYak6lHipOpJ4qJq16NT9dLjoN5GZ6jiVj8CUxlTjmA97EpPTxke@wNuz92BI@eYjA6whxDI2Y8SpcCraJyCYUMk9m9bKTOn/cyW4jNvXw)

Must be called with `source(echo=FALSE)` to prevent the return value from being printed automatically. The alternative would be to [wrap everything in `invisible`](https://tio.run/##XYhLDsIgFACvQoiL9@rz024Nd2i8AaVUXkLRAFUa49mxbt3MTCZWz0PUcYXZZncfE1YOT048eAtXOy7GwrQEk/keoNCK6cXZOFiJVdm3NKpyaGlWpenIqXLqqFdvozMUvJQPUlqGlCNYD5vSw3OG2/ZA2mOzkyQlJaMDbIFIUvzYUot0RqySgxF9ZPFvWzgLp/0k5sVnWb8) but that's much less golfy (and ruins my [still] nice byte count).

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 25 bytes

```
Î€¬"idmhPe"S"><·;=q"S‡J.V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cN@jpjWH1ihlpuRmBKQqBSvZ2Rzabm1bqBT8qGGhl17Y///R6pl5yeo6CuoBRZkgCh8vtSKzBERnJOakgejc0pwS9VgA)

Maps each of the language function with the corresponding 05AB1E function (using the first char of each function), and then executes the resulting string as 05AB1E code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>110</s> <s>91</s> 82 bytes

`exit` will cause the program to exit with an error.

```python
x=0
for c in input():c=='P'==print(x,end='');x+=(1,-1,x,-x/2,c,0)['ndmhx'.find(c)]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##XcXBCsIwDADQu1@RW1rMdNObI/@wu3iQdmWBLSulg/j11bPw4OVPXXa9t2bcn9JeIIDoTz6q84/AjBMy5yJandGskRH9aGd2A3UDGXV2vVGg3j9R47YYXpJodMG/WhMNMBWB/2eTCst7TbAda/0C)

Comment: Shorten your variable names to save 9 bytes. `i='x+=1';d='x-=1';...` and then in your `exec` call, change it to `exec(eval(c[0]))`

Comment: @mypetlion Thanks, but I found a better way.

Comment: I think this is valid: [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##XcXBCsIwDADQu1@RW1rMdNObI/@wu3iQdmWBLSulg/j11bPw4OVPXXa9t2bcn9JeIIDoTz6q84/AjBMy5yJandGskRH9aGd2A3UDGXV2vVGg3j9R47YYXpJodMG/WhMNMBWB/2eTCst7TbAda/0C "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Lynn That's great! I couldn't think of a nice way to short-circuit to the `print` statement!

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 121 bytes

```
func[s][v: 0 parse s[any[["i"(v: v + 1)|"d"(v: v - 1)|"m"(v: v * 2)|"h"(v: v / 2.0)|"P"(prin v)|"e"(exit)]thru" "| end]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCoMwEEX3nuIzK21pa116itJtyEJMggENEqO04N3TRFTaugiTN/P@t1L4pxSMJ6r0ajQ1GzibSuToKztIDKwyb8ZIUxq2E864ZzOJlS4LdSudUARqVrqhuOaBH5T2VhtM4S8plS/tMu4aOxJohjSCc@4VSJsa2xOyxsNqRJmSGHcgSoIVL9HoxtbtelB/re@uxWyqVu2NcX304/V/LvaSjS3HzFZL/gM)

### Readable:

```
f: func [s] [
    v: 0
    parse s [
        any [
            [ "i" (v: v + 1)
            | "d" (v: v - 1)
            | "m" (v: v * 2)
            | "h" (v: v / 2.0)
            | "P" (prin v)
            | "e" (exit)]
            thru [" " | end]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>131</s> <s>125</s> <s>122</s> <s>121</s> <s>118</s> <s>117</s> 115 bytes

```python
v=0;o=""
for x in input().split("x")[0].split():
 if"Q">x:o+=`v`
 else:v+=(1,-1,v,-v/2.)['idmh'.find(x[0])]
print o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxDoMgFEDRna94eYsQ0aqjDf2GdjYmNlXCSygQpYR@PXVocpez3PCNxruhlKS6q1eITPsdMpA7C5/IRXsES5FjRjF1819iZEAaH3jLo6/VkhYGmz22MdWK97LpZZJNugytmCpa36ZqNbmV5/MgZhZ2chF8KUjuBeZpNdx3wh8)

-6 and -3 with thanks to @Rod

-3 and -2 with thanks to @etene

-1 by replacing `"Pri"==x` with `"P"in x`

Comment: you can `split` on `"exit"` and get the 1st block, instead `break`ing [saving 4 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsMgEADvvmLZS7RJ09SjxT/0HgIpjSELVsVYsa@3KRRmLnOY8Embd7LWrIeb14hs9REKkDsI78RFvwdLiaMplFCMw/QPQjGgFe@RUOuifKvnPDMwdjcqa57ba5fPhyfZ5YvsxcgbWl5bI3pyiym8HCsxsRDJJfC1IrknbA@7wm/5BQ)

Comment: You can remove the parentheses around `'idmh'` and use `find` instead of `index`, that will save a few bytes

Comment: @Rod - can actually take that a bit further and split on `ex`to save another 2

Comment: You can replace `v=(v+1,v-1,v*2,v/2.)` with `v+=(1,-1,v,-v/2.)` it should work, didn't tested though

Comment: @Rod - thought about that but couldn't work out how to do the `half`. So simple! Thanks.

Comment: A bit dirty, but you can save 2 more bytes by replacing `if"P"in x` with  `if"Q">x`

Comment: @etene - Thanks. I didn't know that worked for whole strings. Thought it was just individual characters.

Comment: Look at my last edit, actually since `str.find` returns -1 if the substring isn't found, you can remove the last letter in `'idmh'` and it works the same thanks to negative indexing.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>83</s> 79 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to @l4m2*

Iteratively replaces the instructions with either the output or empty strings.

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/\S+./g,w=>m<s?'':w<{}?m:(m+={d:-1,e:w,i:1,m}[w[0]]||-m/2,''),m=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc/dCoIwFAfw@55i7Eal6dToZrh6haDL6kLmrMWm4SyD8tmtGX2ZRQfG4LDf/5xt40OsWSF2pZvlCW9S2mg60V7BdzJm3MbL@dDDa1TRiYr01LJIFZ3qqSK2GtJTQtwAcVIhQQKk6kW18Fer89lVOESW5SBFfadheaZzyT2Zr@3UhiJj4H4SzsCsEIAfRQnBWzkOwBiEg442wki1l@Uj5hrxn36d3SZsYpk@NjBt@NSjPm3edu/WtkkmE950EH74Lz/t1s37fdPf1oW/tDduLg)

#### Commented

```javascript
s =>                       // given the input string s
  s.replace(/\S+./g, w =>  // for each word w in s:
    m < s ?                //   if m is a string:
      ''                   //     ignore this instruction
    :                      //   else:
      w < {} ?             //     if w is 'Pri' ({} is coerced to '[object Object]'):
        m                  //       output the current value of m
      : (                  //     else:
          m +=             //       add to m:
            { d: -1,       //         -1 if w is 'dec'
              e: w,        //         w  if w is 'exit' (which turns m into a string)
              i: 1,        //         1  if w is 'inc'
              m            //         m  if w is 'mult'
            }[w[0]]        //       using the first character of w to decide
            || -m / 2,     //       or add -m/2 (for 'half') if the above result was falsy
        ''),               //       do not output anything
    m = 0                  //   m = unique register of our mighty CPU, initialized to 0
  )                        // end of replace()
```

Comment: `s=>s.replace(/\S+./g,w=>k<s?'':w<{}?k:(k+={d:-1,e:w,i:1,m:k}[w[0]]||-k/2,''),k=0)`

Comment: @l4m2 This `w<{}` is pure evil :p

Comment: `s=>s.replace(/\S+./g,e=>m<s?'':e<{}?m:(m+={d:-1,e,i:1,m}[e[0]]||-m/2,''),m=0)` also work

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>77</s> 75 bytes

(Borrowed (*stole*) @Arnauld's trick of using `m` as the variable name, saving 2 bytes.)

```
f=([c,...s],m=0)=>c<'x'?(c=='P'?m:'')+f(s,m+({h:-m/2,d:-1,n:1,m}[c]||0)):''
```

Recursively walks the string, looking for distinct letters per instruction and ignoring the rest:

- n: inc
- d: dec
- m: mult
- h: half
- P: Pri
- x: exit

Takes advantage of the fact that `undefined` is neither greater than nor less than `'x'`, causing the recursion to stop at the end of the string *or* when it encounters the `'x'` in **exit**.

```js
f=([c,...s],n=0)=>c<'x'?(c=='P'?n:'')+f(s,n+({h:-n/2,d:-1,n:1,m}[c]||0)):''

console.log(f('inc inc inc dec Pri exit'));                 //--> 2
console.log(f('dec inc mult inc inc Pri'));                 //--> 2
console.log(f('inc inc inc mult half Pri exit inc'));       //--> 3
console.log(f('inc Pri inc Pri inc Pri exit half mult'));   //--> 123
console.log(f('Pri exit'));                                 //--> 0
console.log(f('inc half Pri exit'));                        //--> 0.5
```

Comment: Following up to your deleted comment to which I can of course no longer reply, I forgot to paste in the link to the corrected code (d'oh!) but I found a new approach that's 2 bytes shorter than my original attempt anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
≔⁰ηＦ⎇№θx…θ⌕θxθ≡ιn≦⊕ηd≦⊖ηm≦⊗ηh≦⊘ηrＩη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@xCsIwEIb3PsXRKYEKzjpJRXQoOPgCZxJNIE1sktaK@OwxpTpEnI77/o87fibRMYs6xo336mrIsgJJ18XFOiAn4Qy6B6ltbwLpKijHklbQWM2nbacM/9KEO0rB31VgEoii8CwYegGlKVfQ4O1z/mCYE60wQfD50SzxTNqKv1KbS7Y/61yQmbBHPeS5S/nRqdSlRh@IpCl5xagMmzD8TjGqABL1BdpehyIuBv0G) Link is to verbose version of code. Inspired by @RickHitchcock's answer. Explanation:

```
≔⁰η
```

Clear the variable.

```
Ｆ⎇№θx…θ⌕θxθ≡ι
```

Truncate the input at the `x` if there is one, then loop over and switch on each character of (the remainder of) the input.

```
n≦⊕η
```

`n` i**n**crements the variable.

```
d≦⊖η
```

`d` **d**ecrements the variable.

```
m≦⊗η
```

`m` **m**ultiplies the variable by two (i.e. doubles).

```
h≦⊘η
```

`h` **h**alves the variable.

```
rＩη
```

`r` p**r**ints the variable cast to string.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Sorry, didn't test that thoroughly enough. I found a workaround but it cost me a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 107 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>s.split` `.map(([o])=>F?0:o=="i"?i++:o=="d"?i--:o=="m"?i*=2:o=="h"?i/=2:o=="P"?S+=i:F=1,F=i=0,S="")&&S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BioMwFADv@xUhBzFrtK32UFxevXkueBShQWP7lmiksWX/3k1CtyzSQ8gQZl6Sb/EQpr3hNMej7uSy9GDgaBIzKZzP5JwMYgrDWjcMjmWxzTUARVpgFHnsLMaxx8HiJ6Ser5Y3Tz7RoooA8xJ2vASELa@AUhYE1dLq0WglE6UvYR9SHFvytzrZktMNifzBmTKAlH2sbGc4c7ir@ZXZhDLyTv8/3CdXofrXFe7Yhxn7elc6b737zk9x89wjd2nGVp@q9w2vDw0/cJJZoxfKSPYL)

Comment: [Shaved off two bytes](https://tio.run/##bYw7D4IwFEZ3f0XTgbTyEB0xFzZmEkZjgPCQawolgMZ/j22jxBCHpiftOd@9eBZTOeIwu72s6qWBJYMw86ZB4JyT3OuKgbGLvHII48gPJABFGqFtG6wUuq7BTuEeToZbxYcPJzRKbcAghqMTA4LvpEApt6x0KWU/SVF7Qt5Ywyj2Jfmeqi5JMiKpXzhTzncbVX9rrXuIeW2U/0f9XTV6W4hm3dbPKjr/q7SzvU1jFvSWKpc3 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: This as it is should be counted as 105 bytes afaik, as long as your function doesn't call itself you don't need to count `f=`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 107 bytes

```
s=>eval('x=0;x'+(s.split` `.map(v=>({i:"++",d:"--",m:"*=2",h:"/=2",P:";alert(x)",e:"//"})[v[0]]).join`;x`))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 91 bytes

```javascript
_=>_.split` `.map(o=>o<{}>!_?S+=+i:o<"e"?i--:o<"f"?++_:o<"i"?i/=2:o<"j"?i++:i*=2,i=S="")&&S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxBCoMwEEX3PUWahWhTLbi0jl6h4AE0xNiORCNqS6H07DYRKiIuhvnMvPdr/uKD6LEb/VaXcqpgyiHJg6FTOBakCBreuRoSHX@@yTFPMwYMIx1TSVP0fZsqmjKW24TmdoHQxtpExiI8QXhGyIBSz3GySeh20EoGSt/dyqXYCvKfUgpy65HIN47U8w4b1L4t1jzVuDiG30HXrTP@4Kpaulfidc@03HbP3txi@4w5/QA)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 96 bytes

```javascript
_=>_.split` `.map(o=>F?0:o<"Q"?S+=i:o<"e"?i--:o<"f"?F=1:o<"i"?i/=2:o<"j"?i++:i*=2,F=i=0,S="")&&S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzLDoJADEX3fgWZBQF5iCzRwo61hg8AAjNaMjAE0Pj3OCWRGMKi6U17zm3KdzlWA/aT16mazwLmHOLcH3uJU2EUflv2loI4TYJIXdmdJZkDSJGzBD2PkmBJCmdKqG8nCCk2OjpOhEcI3RQQAjcDxmzTzOZKdaOS3JfqYQmLYVcZv6l5ZdwGNPgHJ2bbhw1Kb8Lal5xWR/M76H/rgj9LKdZuOmvpsmcRs92LszRQlzbnLw)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 99 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.split` `.map(_=>eval('++i7--i7++e7u+=+i7i*=27i/=2'.split(7)[Buffer(e+_)[0]%11%6]),e=i=u='')&&u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY09D4IwFAB3f0UXbWv5EAc7PQYHZndDsMJDn6lAaGv679HExThdbrjcw7yMa2eafDqMHS553uE13CBCKdpxcKPFzI43EWUS5aqCxUHpMjdZ8hd2yZ5mEg2U@DJWcKVIpylppVAHBR@jLew15bDn30RoeT6GvsdZoGrkeVevi2J9qGWCQBCAc7nZhOV3XAlOQ8tOM7F/YiTP7sb27Bms51Kuljc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>114</strike> <strike>110</strike> <strike>109</strike> 116 bytes

Actually would have taken two bytes less in Python 2 because `exec` is a statement and doesn't need parentheses...

- *Saved 4 extra bytes thanks to @ElPedro*
- *Saved an extra byte by taking advantage of the fact that `find` returns -1 on error, which can then be used as an index*
- *+7 bytes because I hadn't noticed the no-newlines rule :(*

```python
i=0;exec(";".join("i+=1 i-=1 i*=2 i/=2 print(i,end='') exit()".split()["idmhP".find(h[0])]for h in input().split()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY29DsMgEINf5XRLoD80bceId8geZagCiKvIBREipU@fwtClkvXZg2XHT/YLP4@DdNvZ3U4CO1TvhVggnfUd6Fpx0g@gW0FMxFnQxbLRTSPB7pSFRLXGUMOAZGbfo3LERvihHeXolgQeiIviVjq/rpTllSfoE8G/11nwr@Bg3kL@Ag)

Maps the first character of every input word to a piece of Python code. These are then concatenated and `exec`ed.

Pretty straightforward approach, that could probably be golfed a bit more. The difficulty mostly resides in finding the shortest form out of many possible ones...

Comment: 112 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BCsIwEER/ZdnTrmKseiz5h95LT0lKVnQT0gj162sqFGaGOTxm8rfGpI9tE9v1YQ2OsEfzTKJEKGd7A7nscbJ3kGuLXEQrCUNYpRIjmyW/9jai@HccAppZ1FMcu4mnORWIINqUPw06YOb2qA4O@@BgKPIf/QE "Python 3 – Try It Online") if you have the commands as a space seperated string and split it.

Comment: 110 in fact as the brackets can go [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCsIwFESv8vmrRDFWXZbcofvSVZKSEf0JaYR6@poKhZlhFo@Z/K0xyWPbYLs@rMEp7tk8E0QxzvZGuOxxsnfCtUUukKqgKayoSrNZ8msvI8O/4xDYzBCv4thNeppToUiQpvxp0AFr3f7E0WEfHA0F/80f "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: This doesn't give the correct output. The question says you must print without separators, so you need `print(i,end='')`. See the 4th test case.

Comment: I hadn't noticed, I'll fix it. Thanks !

Comment: @etene Comment when you've fixed it and I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) + `-na`, <s>81</s> <s>73</s> 65 bytes

```ruby
x=0;$F.map{|w|eval %w{x+=1 x-=1 1/0 $><<x x*=2 x/=2}[w.ord%11%6]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8LWwFrFTS83saC6prwmtSwxR0G1vLpC29ZQoUIXSBjqGyio2NnYVChUaNkaKVTo2xrVRpfr5RelqBoaqprF1v7/n5mXrJBbmlOClcAliSoO51HIICQcUJT5L7@gJDM/r/i/bl4iAA)

Pretty straightforward. For the first letter of each word, find the corresponding command string and `eval` it. Uses integer division, and `exits` by throwing a `ZeroDivisionError`.

-5 bytes: Use `.ord%11%6` instead of a string lookup. Credit goes to [user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163573/77973)

-3 bytes: `.ord` only considers the first character of the string, so I can skip a `[0]`.

-8 bytes: Use `-a` flag to automatically split input, thanks to [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)

Comment: You can save even more bytes by adding `-a` option to do the autosplit for you, like [this](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8LWwFrFTS83saC6prwmtSwxR0G1vLpC29ZQoUIXSBjqGyio2NnYVChUaNkaKVTo2xrVRpfr5RelqBoaqprF1v7/n5mXrJBbmlOClcAliSoO51HIICQcUJT5L7@gJDM/r/i/bl4iAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 93 bytes

```hs
(0!)
a!(c:t)|c=='P'=show a++a!t|c>'w'=""|1<2=(a+sum(lookup c$zip"ndmh"[1,-1,a,-a/2]))!t;a!e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc0xDoIwFADQ3VP8NiZtA0RhVL9nYFeHnwrS0JaGlpAYzm51dnrjGyiOnbW5x3uWR6Z2xKQ@JbVpRNEKjMO0AhUFsbTpq1gFcr7VlwYlFXFx0k7TuATQ@7cJ3D/dwG91WdUllRUdmodSLJ2JddhlR8YDQpiNT/CruPEa2tnAn1zlj@4tvWKudAhf)

Essentially a translation of [mbomb007's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163596/3852).

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 207 bytes

```
s=0;n=0;for a in io.read():gmatch'.'do if s==0 then s=1;n=a=='i'and n+1 or a=='d'and n-1 or a=='m'and n*2 or a=='h'and n/2 or n;if a=='P'then print(n)elseif a=="e"then break end elseif a==' 'then s=0 end end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 270 bytes

```
c 0j jincc➕c 1jdecc➖c 1jmultc✖️c 2jhalfc➗c 2jPric 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBfDsFAEMbfnWKOgJO4gmwrVtBESDwiEkGoP201ITaCV8/O4wL2Bsxs19JqxcN0d7q/b2a@sRtOjTPHsh9SLKZSeAcpZiNKAkzOlGBcGOQxHdTwjsDqiO8@/hCggYkU4RZfvRNvMjqM8Lb3GRTwOsaYGsyyk1iQhjU69Xac2wX3q8ug@IVWy/VKouQmjSu1@BtbDskyds5rbq3lc52reNAnJ4Xbp9ccRJtRXuEVaAiwNNhdriZGPOxFjTAxEsIIJ2NGq0fKkHx2UTJyanqBXvgPMaHJU0lVodeKMwr84YlqxmbSLC7uCQ)

```
c 0
j 
jincc➕c 1
jdecc➖c 1
jmultc✖️c 2
jhalfc➗c 2
jPric 10



 inc inc inc dec Pri exit

 dec inc mult inc inc Pri

 inc inc inc mult half Pri exit inc

 inc Pri inc Pri inc Pri exit half mult

 Pri exit

 inc half Pri exit
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 165 bytes

```
	P =INPUT ' exit ' 
	x =0
S	P LEN(1) $ L ARB ' ' REM . P	:S($L)F(end)
i	X =X + 1	:(S)
d	X =X - 1	:(S)
P	O =O X		:(S)
m	X =X * 2	:(S)
h	X =X / 2.	:(S)
e	OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc5NC4JAFIXh9Z1fcRaCM0WW4kqYRZFBYM7gB7itNBwwhWrhv5@ModXlue/mvMfpNg2xtaQhz7muK/joZvNZDqMZcsfKJWVpzkMBDxn2xWFpPor0ggCakpJ7mTjxbmwFM9RANlgjpISXgrXOm781KUiFhhyfLq8QOffOW0SBe3Sk6uo3SiqW5kdrzXhHfx0e0C/zBQ)

Gross.

```
	P =INPUT ' exit ' 				;* append ' exit ' to the input to guarantee that the program will stop
	x =0						;* initialize x to 0 else it won't print properly if the program is 'Pri'
S	P LEN(1) $ L ARB ' ' REM . P	:S($L)F(end)	;* set L to the first letter of the word and goto the appropriate label
i	X =X + 1	:(S)
d	X =X - 1	:(S)
P	O =O X		:(S)				;* append X to the output string
m	X =X * 2	:(S)
h	X =X / 2.	:(S)				;* divide by 2. to ensure floating point
e	OUTPUT =O					;* print whatever's in O, which starts off as ''
END
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# (.NET Core), 186 Bytes

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){int v=0;foreach(var s in a){var i=s[0];if(i=='i')v++;if(i=='d')v--;if(i=='m')v*=2;if(i=='h')v/=2;if(i=='P')System.Console.Write(v);if(i=='e')break;}}}
```

Comment: You can shave 26bytes off this by doing a few simple things, like declaring `i` with `v`, consulting an ASCII table so you can use small numbers, rearranging the `if`s, and then using a ternary: `class Z{static void Main(string[]a){int v=0,i;foreach(var s in a){i=s[0]%'d';if(i==1)break;if(i>9)System.Console.Write(v);else v=i<1?v-1:i<5?v/2:i<6?v+1:v*2;}}}` (P.S. an explanation of how it works and how to use it (e.g. expects command line args) is always appreciated!)

Comment: (Oh that is embarrassing... I should have use `%50` instead of `%'d'`)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 61 bytes

```perl
eval'$,'.qw(++ -- ;exit ;print$,||0 *=2 /=2)[(ord)%11%6]for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHXUVHXa@wXENbW0FXV8E6tSKzRMG6oCgzr0RFp6bGQEHL1khB39ZIM1ojvyhFU9XQUNUsNi2/yMHt///MvGSFjMScNIWAokwFkMZ/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usmAgA)

Stole @user202729's `ord%11%6` trick

### How?

```perl
-a            # split the input by whitespace, store in @F
eval          # Execute the string that results from:
'$,'          # $, (the accumulator)
.             # appending:
qw(           # create an array for the following whitespace separated values:
++ --            # operators for inc & dec
;exit            # exit
;print$,||0      # Pri  (||0 ensures that 0 is output if accumulator is null
*=2 /=2)         # mult div
[(ord)%11%6] # @user202729's trick selects one of the preceding operations
for@F        # for every term input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>120</s> <s>114</s> 111 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to ceilingcat.

```c
x,d;f(char*s){for(x=0;s>1;s=index(d^1?s:"",32)+1)d=*s-100,x+=d?d==5:-1,x*=d^9?d^4?1:.5:2,d+20||printf("%d",x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9disMgFIWf6ypEKGiiQ8y0DxOx2cKsIBC8SSq0aYlpEdquPROFhE4f5Mo537k/RnTGTJPnoFpqjvWQOPZoLwP1OlPuIJXTtofGU6hk6QpC@HfOUslAJ07ILOM@1VCC1vtCSO4TDdVPCdWulMXXvsg5pHn2fF4H248tJVsg3DP1mu4XC7iLA/E8ET3QZmXETjoshDhgwrFjCm1aGsv1NjpKyPx9ITTD@FzbnsZwR4ntDV4eNAb/DhY33o6BD37Qgne@ncYVnKHFf89H5lif2rVLkN/JoH/WyMVUyC/05x6B/tc6HjT9AQ)

## 124 bytes

Floating-point version:

```c
d;f(char*s){for(float f=0;s>1;s=strchr(s,32)+1)d=*s-80,f+=d==25,f-=d==20,f*=d^29?d^24?1:.5:2,s=d^21?s:"",d?:printf("%f",f);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9hisMgEIV/11OIsGBSXZq0hd0EmyvsCRaCdhIhTYpjl4XSs2dVSOj2h87w3vfGUctO63k2NXDdty7H7A6T4zBMraegdjWeihoVeqd7x1Hsy2xbZEblKD92ArbKKFUeBcjUBCVX5rv8bMJ1aIrq/ViVAqNUNFgxJkxTXZ0dPXD2BkxAVj/mn8ka2qX3aViA3MlmZeShQCqlPFEmKGY12QBP5XrzyBkL7YOQANNLa0eewh1ndtR0Oeas6Zez9PxrfeSjH7XoXW6DX8EALf5zPjF9O8A6JcrPZNRfa@JSKuYX@nWPSP8bnT40/wE)

I did not bother with a version that rounds down, but makes an exception for 0, which would be allowed, if I understand the comment-chain correctly.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 44 Bytes

```
Vmx"idmhPe"hdcwd=Z@[hZtZyZcZ2ZZ)NIqN4pZIqN6B
```

[Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Vmx%22idmhPe%22hdcwd%3DZ%40%5BhZtZyZcZ2ZZ%29NIqN4pZIqN6B&input=inc+inc+inc+mult+half+Pri+exit+inc&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=inc+inc+inc+dec+Pri+exit%0Adec+inc+mult+inc+inc+Pri%0Ainc+inc+inc+mult+half+Pri+exit+inc%0Ainc+Pri+inc+Pri+inc+Pri+exit+half+mult%0APri+exit%0Ainc+half+Pri+exit&debug=0)

### explanation

```
Vmx"idmhPe"hdcwd=Z@[hZtZyZcZ2ZZ)NIqN4pZIqN6B   ## full program
             cwd                               ## split input on space
Vmx"idmhPe"hd                                  ## iterate through list of numbers corresponding to operators
                =Z@[hZtZyZcZ2ZZ)N              ## assign the variable Z (initialliy Zero) it's new value
                                 IqN4pZ        ## print Z if the current operator is "Pri" (4)
                                       IqN6B   ## break if the current operator is "exit" (5)
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 112 bytes

This takes advantage of some assumptions that are AFAIK perfectly acceptable.  Number one being that all variables are initialized to zero prior to execution; number two being that input is taken via `Ans`.

```
Ans+" E→Str1
While 1
I+4→I
sub(Str1,I-3,1→Str2
A+(Ans="I")-(Ans="D
If inString("MH",Str2
Then
I+1→I
2AAns+A/2(1-Ans
End
If Str2="P
Disp A
If Str2="E
Stop
Ans→A
End
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 164 bytes

```java
a->{int c=0;for(String g:a.split(" ")){char b=g.charAt(0);if(b==105)c++;if(b==100)c--;if(b==109)c*=2;if(b==104)c/=2;if(b==80)System.out.print(c);if(b==101)return;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVHdSsMwFL7vUxx6lThaO1FQSwUfQCrsUrxI07TLbNOSngyl7NlrUmemA6FehOQ7nO@P7NieRV0v1K58m3jDhgGemFRjACAVCl0xLiAf950sQZMNaqlqYDQ92IUBGUoOOeQGe4OQwcSih9HygGdJWnWeUN@zeOgbiSSEkNKRb5mGIqtj93hEktBUVqTIsnVyQ/lq5VFCeRR5dEf5RXbl4TXllx7eJnTzMaBo485g3FtbJPwku6ZaoNEqPRym1GbvTdHY7McKc73W9j4GfnlldAy@asWahFJx@D6l4PCsJYh3iSFNg3PXRhE7PXHdvuO1pkEvYgWWcH/6zvwtayrv7sZLVRzn/J41ZkWnvUTpP72dy6@4f5MC@ymf)

Above is my solution that rounds off to integers, but below is my solution that handles decimals. The obnoxious way that java prints doubles adds another 55 byes to the score. I left the new lines to make the code more readable in the second submission only because it’s essentially the same solution with one extra command and an import statement.

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 219 bytes

```java
a->{
double c=0;
for(String g:a.split(" ")){
char b=g.charAt(0);
if(b==105)c++;
if(b==100)c--;
if(b==109)c*=2;
if(b==104)c/=2;
if(b==80)System.out.print(new DecimalFormat("0.#").format(c));
if(b==101)return;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVHRSsMwFH3PV1zqS7LR2ImCWioI4ptM2KP4kKXplpmmJb2dk7Jvr2k31zkQ5kNIzuWec@65WYm1CItS2VX60eq8LBzCytc4qg3yUUykEVUFL0LbhgBoi8plQiqYNutCp@DoDJ22CxAs3vqGCgVqCVOY1ljWCAm0InxoSFrUc6NAJlFMsuLAWtwLXpVGIw0gYKwhcikczJMF7x6PSCMWE53ReZJMohsmx@MBRkyG4QDvmBwlVwO@ZvJywLcRm31VqHJe1MhLb47Uqk94UlLnwjwXLhd@iIhfBIxnOyTZkfmEOYW1s/F228Y@aOnz@KD7vP0ucr@kfbC3d@HD7HbAHQ20lfBzUiXh1WlQG42Bdzidy1jqqwO36@94eW3wIOIFzuEe@/b8pTDZwb0rn6vScU7vXqNX7LTPUfpP7s7l17h/k4j/lG8)

Comment: [143 bytes](https://tio.run/##lVHdSsMwFL7vUxx6laCt2dALG2rxAWTCLsWL0yztsvWP9HQoZc8@kzqnDoR5ET5ycr4/ssEdRm2nm81qe1AV9j08oWnGAMA0pG2BSsNi3LVmBZYtyZqmBORy7xZ6QjIKFrAYqBsIUjhg9DA6HqhUXOeyaE@UMsG47ypDLISQ8zFPy1it0T4SEzyaCSHVVZqn6V02SxyILJrwPlMebjN1M49UIqQpmLtHc8GX7z3pOm4HijtnQUzx4@uM51bjVu73B@lidkNeuZjHtFOT2lU8Jnt5RT4Gnw1iy0LTKPg6K63g2RrQb4ZCLoNzy6phbvrN9fueVw8VnUScwCXcn74Tf41VcXL340tVPOccJ41J0WtfovSf3t7lV9y/SYH7lA8 "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 62 bytes

```
s'i'{1a}'d'{1m}'m'{2x}'h'{2d}'P'{o}'e'{@}It[mzsjk""ltqztItn1a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/79YPVO92jCxVj0FSOXWqueqVxtV1KpnAKmUWvUA9er8WvVU9WqHWs@S6Nyq4qxsJaWcksKqEs@SPMPE2P//AQ)

This program takes the instructions delimited by newlines

### Explanation:

```
It[mzsjk""ltqztItn1a]
  [mz            n1a] | Forever
It    jk       It     | - Get the first character of the next instruction
            qz        | - Call the function declared previously
     s  ""lt  t       | - Make sure we don't lose track of the variable
```

The code before that segment defines all the functions.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 152 bytes

```javascript
i=>{return n="",p=0,e=1,i.split(" ").map(i=>{e&&("inc"==i&&p++,"dec"==i&&p--,"mult"==i&&(p*=2),"half"==i&&(p/=2),"Pri"==i&&(n+=p),"exit"==i&&(e=0))}),n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BDoIwEEWv0syi6UhBdOVmPINXaLDomFqaUoiJ4ewVUDauJv9lXt7DjKZvIodUjqfcUmY6v6NNQ/TCE4AOVGtLB81VHxwnBQKwepqglkcrpQL2DRCxlKEoNFzttspSw3Nw6TtV2NERNdyNazeyX8kl8g/4gsIM7Is3yVKNOKH2U24633fOVq67qXatitkU/3eRxRIRaxsxfwA)